Conway's Game of Life object oriented java
Different numbers always appear in the console when you call up the neighbours function, but never the actual neighbours.
public int nachbarn = 0;
    for(int i=(x-1); i<(x+2); ++i) {
        for(int u=(y-1); u<(y+2); u++){
            try{
                if(zellenwert[i][y]) nachbarn += 1;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}
        }
    }
    if(zellenwert[x][y]) nachbarn -= 1;
    return nachbarn;
}

public void setZellenwert(int x, int y, boolean wert) {
    zellenwert[x][y] = wert;
}

public void getZellenwert() {
    for(int i = 0; i<koordinatex; i++){
        System.out.println();
        for(int u = 0; u<koordinatey; u++){
            if(zellenwert[i][u]) System.out.print("X ");
            else System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zelle zelle = new Zelle(10,10);
    Random r = new Random();
    double zufallswert;
    for(int i = 0; i<zelle.getKoordinatex(); i++){
        for(int u = 0; u<zelle.getKoordinatey(); u++){
            zufallswert = r.nextDouble();
            if(zufallswert>=0.5) zelle.setZellenwert(i ,u ,true);
        }
    }
    zelle.getZellenwert();
    System.out.println(zelle.getNachbarn(5,5));
 }

I have checked the getNeighbours function, but I could not find an error.

sorry, but there is no getNeighbours, respectively no getNachbarn method in posted code (probably missing the declaration/first line... ) || anyway, if(zellenwert[i][y]) should probably be if(zellenwert[i][u])  - u instead of y

BTW catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){} is bad bad practice | BTW2 Random has a nextBoolean() method no need to use nextDouble() and compare it to 0.5

I'd say the problem is that you're looping over u, but use y in the if
